# Soap unable to connect to host using .wsdl file php 7.3 Drupal 8

Tags: php, soap, drupal-8

I am trying to get data from two soap apis here is the code for first api that is working fine.

```
public static function data_list()
    {

        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);
        $host = $host = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
        $wsdl = $host . "/modules/custom/upm_api_data/connect/empprof.wsdl";           
        $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl); 

        $params = array('ALL' =>  'ALL');
        $response = $client->__soapCall("ZCIG_FACULTY_STAFF_PROFILE", array($params));      
        return $response;
    }
```

And there is another api that is showing:

> SoapFault: Could not connect to host in SoapClient->__doRequest()
>   error

```
 public static function images_api()
    {
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
        ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);

        $host = $host =  \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
        $wsdl = $host . "/modules/custom/upm_api_data/connect/ImageRac.WSDL";

        $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl);

        $parameters = array('P_PERNR' => "00006629");
        $response = $client->__soapCall("ZCIG_IMAGE_WS", array($parameters));   
        return $response;
    }
```

Second api is working fine in Drupal 7 Php 5.6 but similer code is not working in php 7.3 Drupal 8
I have tried almost every thing related to this issue on internet 
like adding this in options

```
array(
     'stream_context'=> stream_context_create(
        array(
          'ssl'=> array(
             'verify_peer'=>false,'verify_peer_name'=>false
             )
         )
     )
)
```

or

```
array(
        'trace' => 1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
            array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

But not luck I have spent many days on it and I am new to Soap. Can you guys please check what I am doing wrong. 
Thank you for everyone in advance :)

Comment: Can you check if the file extension in this case is `.wsdl` or if it's `.WSDL` ?

Comment: it is  .WSDL, this is the exact file name "ImageRac.WSDL" and i mentioed it is working in php 5.6 (drupal 7) so i think file name or path is not an issue in this case

Comment: Expect the unexpected. Can you share the contents of WSDL with the SoapFault? I would quickly try to reproduce it with both versions.

Comment: i can not share file as its returning data that is senstive for client and there are also some restrictions, we can only run it throug there server

Comment: Make sense. So I'm running out of ideas now. If the code is the same, then the internal hostnames could be interpreted differently in both PHP versions. I'm bit clueless right now. I would create a small `test.php` to isolate the problem. Add the SoapClient with your hardcoded wsdl url and run it through several php versions `5.5`, `5.6`, `7.0`, `7.1`, `7.2`, `7.3` to see if php started to behave differently at a certain major version upgrade. Good luck!

Comment: i am getting host name for both apis in similer manners and its working in first call `data_list()`